# Bash Script - AWK, SED Combined

Tags: awk, sed

I have `.sql` files containing a query as below:

```
begin;
CREATE TABLE public_local.account (
id bigint,
title text,
phone_prefix_list_id bigint,
company_account_id bigint,
created_at timestamp,
updated_at timestamp
);
COMMIT;

begin;
CREATE TABLE public_local.phones (
id integer,
customer_id integer,
company_id integer,
balance_cents bigint,
created_at timestamp,
updated_at timestamp
);
COMMIT;
```

I intend to change only the `CREATE` part so that it would be like this:

```
begin;
INSERT INTO public_global.account SELECT * FROM public.dblink('mercury_local','SELECT * FROM account') as account(
id bigint,
title text,
phone_prefix_list_id bigint,
company_account_id bigint,
created_at timestamp,
updated_at timestamp
);
COMMIT;

begin;
INSERT INTO public_global.phones SELECT * FROM public.dblink('mercury_local','SELECT * FROM phones') as phones(
id integer,
customer_id integer,
company_id integer,
balance_cents bigint,
created_at timestamp,
updated_at timestamp
);
COMMIT;
```

How can I change the `CREATE TABLE` line to `INSERT INTO` line using `AWK` and `SED` inside a bash script?

I have succeeded in creating the `INSERT INTO` lines, but I still can't figure out on how to replace the `CREATE TABLE` lines

Note: I've tried to search the same question or similar but still can't find the same situation as myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
sed '/CREATE TABLE public_local/s/CREATE TABLE public_local.\([a-zA-Z]*\)/INSERT INTO public_global.\1 SELECT * FROM public.dblink(\x27mercury_local\x27,\x27SELECT * FROM \1\x27) as \1/' file.sql
```

So to expand variable, need to use double quotes `"`, and put variable as `${variable_name}` inside, I tried below script, and it worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

country="global"

sed "/CREATE TABLE public_local/s/CREATE TABLE public_local\.\([a-zA-Z_]*\)/INSERT INTO public_${country}.\1 SELECT * FROM public.dblink(\x27mercury_${country}\x27,\x27SELECT * FROM \1\x27) as \1/" file.sql
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can sed use shell variables? as I need to put some variables to the lines also

Comment: @buzzing_bee  Yes, use double quotes instead of single quotes, put `${varName}` inside, and take care of some expanding with escape.

Comment: hi @Tiw , after I try again using your sed, it's only change (replace) the first \1 which is `_ INSERT INTO public_global.\1 _`, the `\1` after that is not replaced. The one inside the bracket and after `as`

Comment: I'm using sed (GNU sed) 4.4 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I copied the sed command from here directly, and just add a underscore at the regex `\([a-zA-Z_]*\)` notice the underscore at the end of the square bracket

Comment: @buzzing_bee  That's strange... It should work imho. Are you using it inside other thing, like some kind of script?

Comment: yes you're correct. I try to put it inside a shell script and inside a loop (for) as I need to replace around hundred tables. Why I do this, because I need to replicate my database using different database structure, so I need to manually replicate each of tables. (there are around 140ish tables on my DB) and I have 5 DB's (maybe more in the future)

Comment: Oh, I meant \ with \\  , They got escaped here too. @buzzing_bee

Comment: tried with double \\ but still no luck. here's my script : `_ sed "/CREATE TABLE public_./s/CREATE public_.\([a-zA-Z_]*\)/INSERT INTO public_\${country}.\\1 SELECT * FROM public.dblink(\x27mercury_\${country} \x27,\x27SELECT * FROM \\1 \x27) as \\1/" $DIR/query.sql >> $DIR_CTY/$query-fix.sql _`  The `\${country}` is a variable containing string taken from a file (i.e australia, japan, etc). And as mentioned, this is inside a for loop

Comment: @buzzing_bee  The backslash \ before `${country}`, I think it's uncessary here.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it's only replace the first occurence and not the rest. It also not reading the shell variable. Result is like this: `_ INSERT INTO public_.customers SELECT * FROM public.dblink('mercury_','SELECT * FROM ') as ( _`

Comment: @buzzing_bee You sure your varible is not empty? Did you remove the \ before `${country}`?  Check my updated content, maybe try the same thing see if it work on your system.

Comment: yes, it is not empty, I try to echo my variable and having a result. but when I throw at the sed command, it is the same. I did copied your sed command, and the result is the same, only replace the first occurence. I also remove the \ before `${country}` it also not work. empty.

Comment: @buzzing_bee  Maybe paste your code at some other place like pastebin or something, and give the link here so I can look at it.

Comment: @buzzing_bee  That's quite a bit... I suggest you to replace the `(` with `\x28`, and `)` with `\x29` first, and then every \ in the sed line with \\, and try again. Also I suggest you simplify it with this one case first...

Comment: I tried to simplify as you suggested but the result is the same. One question: can you explain what this line does : `sed "/CREATE TABLE public_local/s` , is it to search line begins with `CREATE TABLE public_local` ??